# EasyMock assertion exception swallowed by thread

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, apache-camel, easymock

I'm writing unit tests for some legacy code that uses Apache Camel routes and Spring to inject endpoint handlers. This works great in production but is problematic for unit testing with EasyMock because Apache Camel is multi-threaded and swallows `Unexpected method call` exceptions from EasyMock.

I'd love to use mock endpoints, but the app isn't configurable enough to do that without some refactoring. I'd like to get tests in before I do that refactoring.

Essentially I have a route that looks approximately like this:

```
from("direct:input")
  .to("bean:validatorService?method=validate(${header},${body})")
  .choice()
    .when(body().isNotNull())
      .to("bean:processingService?method=continueProcessing(${header},${body})")
  .end()
```

Now I setup my unit test like I normally would, and create a "validatorService" bean with EasyMock. This works great for positive case, I can use EasyMock to expect `validatorService.validate` to be called exactly once. However if `processingService.continueProcessing` gets called next I don't get the EasyMock exception. My guess is that camel swallows the exception in another thread (this guess is consistent with camel debug logs that I've looked through).

Here is a test that works as expected, both methods should be called:
    EasyMock.reset(mockedValidator, mockedProcessor);

```
EasyMock.expect(mockedValidator.validate(
    EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.anyObject()))
        .andReturn("foo").once();

// This method is called, the test passes regardless of whether
// or not the expectation is set because Camel swallows the exception.  
//EasyMock.expect(mockedProcessor.continueProcessing(
//    EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.anyObject()).once();

EasyMock.replay(mockedValidator, mockedProcessor);

inputProducer.sendBody("message");

verify(mockedValidator, mockedProcessor);
```

All this would be solved if there was a "none()" to go with "once()" and "times(N)". But there isn't one I could find.

Comment: Instead of EasyMock use the Camel testing support which allows mocking of endpoints.

Comment: I have the same problem. Good comment, but if I need to mock not and endpoint, but a bean that has nothing to do with Camel??
Winder's problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is indeed a good comment. Camel provides a testing framework with nice assertions and verifies. So I would recommend using that.

Then, about exceptions in thread, the trick is generally to use a `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler` to catch them.

However, indeed, in your case, camel is probably using its own error system. I don't remember what is the default but you might want to manage exception in a specific way.

Finally, are you using a nice mock?

Because a default mock in EasyMock should throw an error on the `verify` if an expected method isn't called. That's why you don't really need a `none`

Comment: The problem isn't testing if an expected method isn't called. That works exactly as you described. Its handling unexpected calls that is a problem because EasyMock fails fast, but that failure is buried in camel. I'll look into the uncaught exception handler, thanks for the suggestion.